# how to make a unique class using foreach?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, foreach

I am having a hard time creating unique class in my div using php. Below this is my code so far:

```
  $show = 0;
    foreach($photo as $row){
        if($show==0){ ?>
            <figure class="<?php echo"show";?>">
                <img src="<?php echo base_url('images/photouploads/'.$row->file_name);?>" width="420" />
            </figure>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    <figure>
      <img src="<?php echo base_url('images/photouploads/'.$row->file_name);?>" width="420" />
    </figure>
  <?php $show++; }?>
```

I want my like this:

```
<figure class="show">lorem ipsum</figure>
<figure>lorem ipsum</figure>
```

as we notice there is only one class that has a value **SHOW**. but now i have one show **BUT** my first image is repeated twice. can anyone of you guys can solve this problem? i need your help. thank you!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? To only use `class="show"` on your first image?

Comment: if you want a unique identifier of your figure why you dont use "id"?

Comment: If you need it to be unique, try adding random numbers after it?

Comment: It's because the there are 2 `img` tags.  Either that or I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the above and fix your issue with much less code by using a ternary operator.

```
$show = 0;
foreach($photo as $row){ ?>
    <figure class="<?php $show == 0 ? echo 'show' : '' ;?>"> //if $show equals 0, class="show" will display
        <img src="<?php echo base_url('images/photouploads/'.$row->file_name);?>" width="420" />
    </figure>
    <?php $show++; 
}?>
```

Your first image is showing twice because you have the image displaying twice when `$show` is 0.  This will fix that for you. Another option would be an `if` / `else` but this is much shorter.

Comment: +1 for removing the repetition in of the HTML code. I would mention though that a ternary operator isn't really needed, you can have a normal if/else with two echoes to achieve the same.

Comment: +1 from me as well, though I'm not sure if it's a good idea to teach ternaries to beginners...

Answer (score 1):

If you just one item with the show class, but no repeating images, simply but the "non-show" part in the else statement:

```
foreach($photo as $row){
    if($show==0)
        $class = 'show';
    else 
        $class = '';
    ?>
    <figure class="<?php echo $class; ?>">
        <img src="<?php echo base_url('images/photouploads/'.$row->file_name);?>" width="420" />
    </figure>
    <?php $show++; 
} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I got the answer now guys.

Here is the code:

```
<?php 
    $test='show';
    foreach($photo as $row){?>                         
    <figure class="<?php echo $test;?>">
      <img src="<?php echo base_url('images/photouploads/'.$row->file_name);?>" width="420" />
    </figure>
  <?php $test=''; }?>
```

**Thanks for your effort answering my question I appreciate it.**

Comment: This will work if you don't use your original `$show` variable as a counter for something.